# Python - cdll immediately crashes program after upgrading from Python 2.7 to 3.8

Tags: python, python-2.7, matlab, dll, python-3.8

I am in the process of upgrading a project from python 2.7 to 3.8, which involved a call of a function from a dll. This dll was actually generated with MATLAB's codegen utility.

The header of the function shown in the .h file from the codegen utility (edited to obscure any details) states:

```
extern void example_func(const double inputArray[12], const struct0_T *inputStruct, double
    value1, double value2, double value3, double returnArray[12]);
```

Now, with Python 2.7 I was able to call this function with the following steps:

```py
from ctypes import *

myDll = cdll.LoadLibrary(path_to_my_library)

# initialized values like so:
inputArray = (c_double*12)()
returnArray = (c_double*12)()
value1 = c_double(value) # etc.
# ...
# ...
# later in the code, after making sure all inputs were cast to the correct ctypes
result = []
myDll.example_func(inputArray, inputStruct, value1, value2, value3, returnArray)

for i in range(0, 12):
    result.append(returnArray[i])
```

This would return the result I was expecting into "result"

Now, when I try and do the same thing with python 3.8, I get to the point where I call `myDll.example_func(...)`, and it immediately terminates the program, and I get the error code:
`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

The DLL is 64-bit, and I am using the 64-bit version of Python 3.8.

I am not sure where to go from here, any direction or help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `struct0_T`? How do you initialize the struct? How do you pass the pointer to the struct when executing `myDll.example_func`?

Comment: @Rotem It is a simple struct filled various doubles. I created a ctypes Structure in python, `inputStruct`, and passed it into the function as shown above - which seemed to work with python 2.7. I did experiment with passing in `ctypes.pointer(inputStruct)`, with no luck.